# Download pdf throgh web view how to do?

Tags: iphone, pdf, download

In my app i have shown pdf from the remote server using webview and i have to add a action to download the pdf and save it into iPhone how to do...Using Php i tried to force download pdf,which works in browser(desktop) not in device

Can any one help me...

Comment: The iPhone doesn't have a public file system API for Safari. You could get around that by mailing the pdf, as mail caches the mails, and thus the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

The (unjailbroken) iPhone's Safari cannot access the local file system, so it's impossible to download anything.

(The iPad, OTOH, may support it.)

Comment: url= @"http://localhost/abc.pdf"
theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] 
cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:kTimeoutLongInterval];
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if (theConnection) {
       receivedData=[[NSMutableData data] retain];
Can i save the 'receivedData'  has a pdf is it possible?
I found a example of getting image in received data and which is saved in device 

imgDownload.image = [UIImage imageWithData:receivedData];
Is that possible in PDF?

Comment: Yes you can save the PDF, but only your app can read it. Saving as image requires the file to be an image first.

Comment: Hi kennyTM,
Thanks for the reply,Can u say me how can i save the received data as a pdf?

Comment: @user: `[data writeToFile:@"somefile.pdf" atomically:YES];`

Comment: Kenny can u post me a brief code...I tried but i could nt recognize that whether file was writed or not especially in simulator...how can i view the file?

Comment: @user: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/BinaryData/BinaryData.html

Answer (score 0):

use the **download** attribute in slide your a tag

`<a href="content/file.pdf" download > pdf link </a>`
  `<a href="content/file.doc" download > doc link </a>`